# Dovecot password hashing

Tags: hash, sha512, dovecot

Can anyone tell me how the Dovecot administration tool (doveadm pw) hashes passwords when using SHA-512. $6$ indicates SHA-512, followed by a salt, then the hash. How exactly does Dovecot generate the salt? Does it use an own algorithm? As far as I can see it uses /dev/random or /dev/urandom, but how does it deal with non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, found out in password-scheme.c.

It reads data from /dev/urandom and has an array with allowed characters (static const char salt_chars[] = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";).

The salt is generated by using one of the characters from that array; precisely, it takes the byte from /dev/urandom modulo the length of salt_chars - 1 and uses that as index to pick a char from salt_chars.